# Deleterecord is not deleting object from the HasMany array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an event model which has a relationship to a rider model. The event model has a property called riders that is a hasMany of riders and it is also async. The rider model has a property called event that is a belongTo and it contains the proper event that it belongs to. I am loading all of my data from my own REST API that is ran via Node.js and Express 4.

Here is my deletion code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRider: function () {
            var model = this.get('model');
            var evt = model.get('event');

            model.deleteRecord();
            model.save().then(function() {
                evt.save();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

models/event.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    state: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('string'),
    riders: DS.hasMany('rider', {
        async:true,
        inverse:'event'
    })
});
```

models/rider.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    state: DS.attr('string'),
    BB: DS.attr('boolean'),
    SB: DS.attr('boolean'),
    BU: DS.attr('boolean'),
    event: DS.belongsTo('event')
});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `model.save()` is completing successfully and that `evt.save()` is therefore being executed?

Comment: Yes, my node.js server receives a DELETE request for the rider and also a PUT request for the event; however, the event's riders property still contains the id of the rider that I just deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Im having problems to understand what are u exactly trying to delete.

But the way i approach this is. There's an array of Model instances and there's an array of toDeleteModelInstances. The first array is shown on template using each method. And during the delete of each instance you use toDeleteModelInstancesArray.pushObject(selectedInstance)

Looks something like this.

Delete

```
deleteFieldset: function(givenRecord){

     //remove from Each array then push to array containing deleted records
    this.get('controller.markedForDeleted.pushObject(givenRecord));
    // You now have a record in given array [class,class]
}
```

Now on EDIT action

```
      var personsToDelete = self.markedForDeleted.map(function(item){ 
        return item.destroyRecord();
      });

      // Checks for deletedInstances array 
      if(Ember.isEmpty(personsToDelete)){
        deletePersonSuccess();
      } else {
        Ember.RSVP.all(personsToDelete).then(deletePersonSuccess, deletePersonFailure);
      }
```